# Spring boot unable to find org.springframework:springloaded:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My searches have come up empty for the Spring package org.springframework:springloaded:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE, so I am looking for advice on what is wrong with my build.  I am new to Spring, so sorry if this is a rookie mistake.

The goal is to build a simple Spring app that I can remote debug.  If I can get this working, then I should be able to get remote debugging on a much larger application.

When I package the application, through Maven I get the error `Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project scott: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE:repackage failed: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework:springloaded:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE in central`

Before this build attempt, I blew away my repo's cache (~/.m2).

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ctl.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>scott</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring Boot Blank Project (from https://github.com/making/spring-boot-blank)</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.20.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version  -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>scott.App</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <rest.assured.version>2.3.3</rest.assured.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency> 
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my application.properties is

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.main.show-banner=false
logging.level.jdbc=OFF
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=DEBUG
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=DEBUG
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false

spring.devtools.remote.debug.enabled=true
```

Any advice, review, or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems there is no version called 2.1.6. The latest available version is 1.2.8. Check this : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/springloaded

Comment: I have seen that, and tried setting that as the version in the springframework.boot plugin dependency section, but it still errors out the same, looking for version 2.1.6.RELEASE.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use those dependencies in the first place (which explains why they don't exist anymore). Read the documentation about the spring boot maven plugin, and about the devtools if that's what you want. Don't use an obsolete, unmaintained, probably incompatible dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Darn it, Chathuranga Chandrasekara was right, after I went back and these two changes to my pom, it builds

In the dependency section I added

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

And changed the plugin section to

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <jvmArguments>
            -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I must have missed something the first time I tried it.

Thanks